# How to create Bootstrap like border on click in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a hamburger menu in CSS. I want to do two things:

- When a user clicks on it, create [bootstrap like](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) border (light colored) as shown in figure below.
- Invert colors when user clicks/hovers on hamburger i.e. change my hamburger border to black, background to white and inner divs to follow same pattern. For this I added a css `:hover`, but don't know how to do that for child elements to follow parent.

---

```
.hamburger:hover {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
```

[image]

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/rcxfwdm9/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple css selectors together

```
.hamburger:hover
```

means selecting all elements with hamburger class when hovering

```
.hamburger div
```

means selecting all div elements inside element with hamburger class

So when combining

```
.hamburger:hover div
```

This means selecting all div elements inside *element with hamburger class when hovering*

```css
.hamburger, hamburger div {
    transition: all .15s;
}

.hamburger div {
    margin: 0.4rem 0px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.hamburger:hover div {
  border-color: #343a40;
}
.hamburger:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(108,117,125,.5);
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #343a40;
}
```

### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/vyr6bc8f/18

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS `box-shadow`.

Example:

```css
.btn-grey {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  color: white;
}

.btn-grey:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px darkgray;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn-grey'>Button</button>
```